# Amplifying sound from a microphone

Tags: piezoelectricity, microphone, amplifier

I have a small piezoelectric ultrasonic microphone (receiving signals of around 40 kHz). But the voltages it generates are too small to be read by my micro-controller's ADC. So I want to amplify the voltage created by the microphone.

I'd like a solution with a low part count, if possible. I've been trying to use an op-amp + some resistors, but I can't figure it out.
So, how can I amplify the voltage from the microphone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piezos have a high output impedance (capacitive, really), so you need an even higher input impedance on your mic pre or you'll get a "tinny" sound from the low end being rolled off.

A piezo with 1000 pF capacitance would have [a reactance of 3 MΩ at 50 Hz](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282*pi*1000+pF*50+Hz%29+to+ohm), for instance, so if you wanted to pick up 50 Hz, you'd need an amp with several MΩ input impedance.

[Signal Conditioning Piezoelectric Sensors](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf) from TI shows a circuit with 10 MΩ input impedance, for instance.   [Interfacing Piezo Film to
Electronics](http://www.eng.hmc.edu/NewE80/PDFs/PiezoElectronics.pdf) suggests 22 MΩ and shows the most basic circuit you could use: one of these big resistors in parallel with a unity-gain buffer op-amp.  If that level is too low, add two resistors and make it into a non-inverting voltage amplifier (figure 9 b):

[image: a charge amplifier and non-inverting voltage amplifier for piezo applications]

> The major advantage of a charge
>   amplifier, therefore, can be found
>   when a long cable is used between a
>   piezo film sensor and electronics. In
>   addition, it also minimizes charge
>   leakage through the stray capacitance
>   around the sensor. Otherwise, simple
>   voltage amplifiers are sufficient for
>   most applications.

[source](http://bmo.tnw.utwente.nl/electronics/Misc/PiezofilmCircuit/interface.stm)